# i am trying to connect to node.js and i have some errors in webstorm

Tags: node.js

**I am trying to connect to server node.js and these is the error i am getting:**

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\cookie-signature'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\content-disposition'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\serve-static'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/extend-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

**this is the package.json:**

ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\cookie-signature'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Auth.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/content-disposition/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\content-disposition'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mime-types/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mime-types'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/serve-static/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\serve-static'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\destroy'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/extend-node.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\send'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Timer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\mysql\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\body-parser\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\express\node_modules\body-parser\lib'

Answer (score 0):

Most of the errors seem to be missing modules:

- `ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js` : The error is occurring in `index.js`
- `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto'` : The error is a missing module (`'crypto'`)
- `in 'C:\Users\amordoch\WebstormProjects\automationDashboard\node_modules\cookie-signature'` : The directory where it is looking for the module.

First you should try installing all the dependencies it's asking for, using `npm`:

1. Navigate to the app's root folder.
2. Run `npm install crypto`.
3. Repeat for all missing modules, replacing `crypto` with the other module's name.

Correcting this should fix most - if not all - the issues.

Comment: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto). i installed most of the modules but the errors is still there

Comment: go to ..\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\browser.js
and you can add : node: {crypto: true, stream: true, fs: 'empty', net: 'empty' , tls: 'empty'}, this resolved my problem